# need cell to stay blank until data id entered into the corresponding cell.

Tags: excel

Here is my situation I have a formula that reads as follows H8+45 in cell I8 now I need cell I8 to stay blank until I enter something into cell H8 I tried =IFERROR(H4+45,"") and it did not work. I also have a conditional format formula that turns the cell red when the 45th day arrives. what can you suggest to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Test directly:

```
=IF(H4="","",H4+45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in cell `I8`,

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H8),"",H8+45)
```